# Fedora 21 reports root file system as 100% full, cannot use yum

Tags: linux, partitioning, fedora

When I try to use a yum command like

> yum update

the terminal yields this:

```
Error: Insufficient space in download directory /var/cache/yum/fedora
    * free   0 
    * needed 100 k
```

When I execute the command

> df -h

to see my partition sizes, it yields this.

```
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                 1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                    1.9G   23M  1.9G   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs                    1.9G  960K  1.9G   1% /run
tmpfs                    1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/fedora-root   50G   49G     0 100% /
tmpfs                    1.9G   20K  1.9G   1% /tmp
/dev/mapper/fedora-home  405G   84G  301G  22% /home
/dev/sda1                477M  133M  316M  30% /boot
tmpfs                    384M  8.0K  384M   1% /run/user/1000
```

As you can see, root is full. I have tried deleting /var/log, Fedora's yum cache, and executing

> yum clean all

to no avail. Please help! My root partition should not be this large.

I also cannot install new applications like gparted to resize the partitions.

Comment: First step will be to figure out what is taking up all that space.  How much space have you used under, say, /root, /usr, /var etc.  If you have a database server on there they often write files under /var/lib so that could be chewing up a lot of space.

Answer (score 2):

It might be that the PackageKit cache is filling up. PackageKit is used by GNOME to handle updates. If you use Yum or DNF on the CLI then don't need these. You can remove the .rpm files in `/var/cache/PackageKit/metadata/updates/packages` and set PackageKit to not store them any longer.

There is a setting in the file `/etc/PackageKit/PackageKit.conf`

```
# Keep the packages after they have been downloaded
#KeepCache=false
```

As root, remove the hash mark on this configuration option and the packages will not be saved.

Answer (score 0):

also if gparted is truly needed grab a usb and a recent copy of  21  livecd iso and use the gparted / or  disk utility pre-loaded / easily installed on it.

Then mount the current  ailing install and resize (presumably with lvm mechanism like so):
lvm lvresize --resizefs  -L -$(some smaller size) /dev/mapper/fedora-home

lvm lvresize --resizefs -L +$(any or all of space form first step) /dev/mapper/fedora-root

partprobe

(optional but highly advised)
recheck /etc/fstab for proper sizing shown here now..

dracut --regenerate-all -f && grub2-mkconfig -o  /boot/grub2/grub.cfg

attempt reboot

Answer (score -1):

1. `cd /`
2. `du -hs *`
3. Delete unwanted files
4. switch in the folder with the highest fill rate you did not already visited or Goto 6.
5. Check if you are still at the root partition. If not

   5.1. `cd ..`
6. Goto 2